# Windows unable to shrink 930GB freshly installed windows partition more than 15GB on kingston SSD even after removing unmoveable files

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I am trying to install Linux (Arch) in a dual-booted system with Windows. The problem is that my windows partition is 930gb out of my Kingston SNVS1000G's 1000GB. I have done a fresh install of windows (with no files from my previous version) but in the process, when it was 15% done cleaning up Windows, it said there was some files it couldn't delete. I cleaned up the freshly installed windows with CHKDSK using:

```
chkdsk c: /f /r /x
```

I've also checked the C: drive for any errors under C:/ properties -> Tools -> Check.

I have disabled anything that might cause unmoveable files (at least according to what I could read online):

Disabled system restore
Disabled hibernation file
Disabled paging file
Disabled kernel memory dump
Still, Windows only allows me to shrink it 15gb.

I also have a fresh windows 11 install ready on a USB drive. In that windows installer, would it be safe for me to delete the main drive that windows is installed on entirely, create a new drive (where I can set the space myself), install Windows, then install Linux?

Kingston seems to want you to use their "Kingston SSD Manager" application to securely erase everything on your SSD, but to do so, "your drive must not contain any partitions". How does one accomplish this, when this windows application must surely run on one of these partitions? Do you have to install windows to another usb og external harddrive that is large enough to run it, install Kingston SSD manager there, then use it to clean the harddrive? But then on this other USB, how do you remove all the partitions currently on the Kingston harddrive?

Comment: "would it be safe for me to delete" - Safe with regards to what exactly?  If you are going to delete all the partitions on the disk.  You can simply install Windows to a smaller partition.  Your question and goals are not clear.

Comment: In additional to Kingston's SSD Manager, many manufacturers provide secure erase tools in their BIOS. For example, my ASUS motherboard comes with one that supports most SSDs. I have used it to securely erase my SSDs multiple times without problem.